# How to do nested menu items in twilio

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I'm working on a menu for IVR with twilio using php. I can't seem to figure out how to do a nested menu. i.e ask for english or spanish, then ask for an id number, then other information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out the [Phone Menu HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/phonemenu?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) available on our website.  This shows how to build a multi-level menu.

Specifically the part you want to look at is the "*Directions*" option in the main menu.  Choosing this menu option from the root menu has the PHP application return a set of TwiML which reads a sub-menu.  That sub-menu is created in the PHP application under the *location* option of the switch statement in *phonemenu.php*.

Hope that helps.